# Camera2 api clicks multiple images on single click

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-image-capture

I am using camera2 api to capture images in my android application. When i am clicking on button to capture image it clicks multiple images on just one click. This issue happens only on few devices. Any suggestion to stop clicking multiple images on one click?

Comment: Your code seems ok! :D

Comment: Lol! You didn't get me :D. You have to paste code here :P

Comment: Try use [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.html#setRepeatingRequest(android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) setRepeatingRequest(args)

Comment: have you found solution

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem.

I've added a boolean flag `captureRequested` which I set to `true` when I send a capture request, and `false` when I receive the image inside the `onImageAvailableListener`.

I'm sure it's not the best answer. If anyone has a better one...